# node-xmpp C2SServer connection issue on registration

Tags: node.js, xmpp, ejabberd, node-xmpp

I am using [node-xmpp](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp) library to communicate with ejabberd server installed on ubuntu.

I have the following script to register and perform actions in the server..

```
var xmpp          = require("node-xmpp");
var c2s = new xmpp.C2SServer({
    port: 5223,
    domain: 'domain.com'
});

c2s.on('connect', function(client) {

    console.log('connect ??? ++++++++');

    c2s.on('register', function(opts, cb) {
        console.log('REGISTER')
        cb(true)
    })
    client.on('authenticate', function(opts, cb) {
        console.log('AUTH' + opts.jid + ' -> ' +opts.password)
        cb(null) // cb(false)
    })

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('DISCONNECT')
    })

});
```

I am able to see the connect message in the server. But its not invoking the register event.

However i have another ejabberd instance in 5222 port which is working fine for registration from Audium XMPP Client.

Answer (score 1):

Just change in the Register event `cb(true)` with `cb(false)`..and should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

`xmpp.C2SServer` is a building block to use if you are writing your own server.

If you want to connect to an existing XMPP server, you need to use:

```
import xmpp from 'node-xmpp-client'
const client = new xmpp.Client( ... )
```

Then follow [XEP-0077](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) to register an account on the server.